# Yarn application stuck with ACCEPTED state

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop-yarn

I know that this question exists already, but I tried all solutions without positive results.
So, I've a cluster with one Namenode with 4GB RAM and three Datanodes with 3GB RAM each.
These are my configurations for yarn-site, mapred-site and spark respectively.

[image]

[image]
[image]

But when I run simple yarn application (map-reduce or spark), this is the result:
[image]

Also, when I check Application Metrics in YARN UI I obtain:
[image]

If I open the Tracking-URL this is my situation:
[image]

Can someone help me? 
Thank you!!

Comment: Can you please post your sprak job config also?

Comment: If you go to the tracking url listed in the output, what's that UI say? And are you sure that your nodemanagers are running? The datanode process doesn't need 3GB to itself, either

Comment: I posted spark config and tracking url result also. Regarding NodeManagers I know that they work fine since I see NodeManagers process running with jps.